# Escaping string before assigning to innerHTML echoed by PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm encountering a problem involving escaping character that I think it's not simple at all. If this is done in javascript, nothing to say but the context is using echo command (in PHP) to write javascript code like this:

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('spanID').innerHTML=\"$x\"</script>";
```

$x is a variable in PHP environment, which can contain both single and double quotes. What I do here is:
1. Keep the $x not change, and if $x contains any double quote, the above code won't work, the text echoed may look like:

```
<script>document.getElementById('spanID').innerHTML="leftside"rightside"</script>;
```

I supposed $x = leftside"rightside, and you can see it surely won't work.

1. Escape the double quotes in $x (change all " to

   ```
   "
   ```

   ), then the text echoed may look like this:

   document.getElementById('spanID').innerHTML="leftside

   ```
   "
   ```

   rightside";

The

```
"
```

won't be converted to " when it is assigned to innerHTML attribute of a Span (for e.g), so instead of my want, the innerHTML of my SPAN should be leftside"rightside, it will be leftside

```
"
```

rightside.

If I change the " to ' in the original echo, like this:

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('spanID').innerHTML='$x'</script>";
```

It is the same because $x here can contain both single and double quotes.

I don't find out any other ways to escape quotes in this case. Could you please help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: What about [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)?

Comment: @VisioN exactly what I was thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put between the quotes a string that is a valid string of JavaScript containing valid (and safe) HTML.

Your best option is to not use `innerHTML` and instead use `document.createTextNode` which means you only need to slash-escape the content.

Otherwise, you need to HTML escape, then slash escape the content.  For correctness, your slash-escaping function should escape at least double-quotes, backslashes, and all JavaScript newlines  (U+A, U+D, U+2028, U+2029).  I believe PHP's `addslashes` does not handle U+2028 or U+2029 by default but [How to escape string from PHP for javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085648/how-to-escape-string-from-php-for-javascript) has some alternatives.

To put it all together:

```
$x_escaped = json_encode($x, JSON_HEX_TAG);

echo "<script>document.getElementById('spanID').appendChild(document.createTextNode($x_escaped))</script>"
```

should do it.  The JSON_HEX_TAG makes sure that `$x_escaped` will not contain `</script>` or any other content that prematurely ends your script tag.  `</script>` will instead become `\u003c/script\u003e`.

Comment: `innerText` is far not the best property for compatibility reasons.

Comment: He :) But how you pass `$x` to `document.createTextNode()` method?

Comment: Your suggestion about innerText may be what I'll try. I'm sorry for my question, I want to type &#034 ; (there's no space before the ;) but it turned to " after I submitted my question. Could you please explain more to me why I need to HTML escape here? All I want to escape are quotes, not all HTML elements, and I did the escape myself, which is simpler, or my escape is not what HTML escaping function do to quotes only (I'm talking about only quotes here). Thanks!

Comment: @KingBoy, please see my edit.  I think the code I added does what you want.