# Escape Javascript in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, string, escaping

I am Trying to escape these darn quotes and stuff in JS. I'm trying to use json_encode. My head hurts from looking at quotes, help???

```
  $list = '';

    // some loop here

   $message = 'centeredPopup(this.href,"myWindow","500","300","yes")';
   $jscode = 'json_encode('.$message.');return false';
   $list .= '<p> 
        <a href="http://www.example.com/something.php?id=' . $id . '" onclick="' 
              .htmlspecialchars($jscode) . '" >' . $name . '</a></p><br>';
```

Comment: Why are you putting the javascript in PHP variables to begin with?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. `json_encode()` is not javascript, so why encapsulate it in a string?

Comment: i was using this example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085648/how-to-escape-string-from-php-for-javascript   
i'm generating a list of links that create popup windows or was trying to. this may not be the best way though ^_^

Comment: I would say rather than putting a long string of javascript inside a onClick attribute, make a named javascript function and have your onClick reference it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *call* json_encode there, you need to do this.

```
$jscode = json_encode($message).';return false';
```

You don't even need json_encode for this. You can put this there:

```
$message = 'centeredPopup(this.href,"myWindow","500","300","yes")';
$jscode = $message.';return false';
$list .= '<p> <a href="http://www.example.com/something.php?id=' . $id . '" onclick="' .htmlspecialchars($jscode) . '" >' . $name . '</a></p><br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$message = 'centeredPopup(this.href,"myWindow","500","300","yes")';
$jscode = json_encode($message);
```

Otherwise everything else should be OK.