# Reading GDPR info from text file, echo out in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I want to read GDPR info from a file, then in PHP echo out a confirm box with the info, and I then set a cookie, using php setcookie.
I have trouble getting it to work:

```
$message = file_get_contents("my_gdpr_text.txt");
echo ('<script>confirm("'.$message.'")</script>');
```

The confirm box just does not pop up at all (not even a blank box). If I set the message value to "Oscar" or anything, it all works, so the problem must be the answer from  file_get_contents. I know it is read correctly, by testing with print_r. Is some text formatting needed? Grateful for answer.

Comment: Please share more details. It should not be too hard to check the generated markup for errors, or your browser's error console

Comment: Well if your `my_gdpr_text.txt` has a double quote in it you're going to break the encapsulation. Please provide rendered code. PHP is simple and likely not the issue (unless `$message` is empty, or you are receiving a 500)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ('<script>confirm("'.$message.'")</script>');
```

The problem with this is that as soon as your `$message` variable contains any double apostrophes `"` your JavaScript breaks
For example

```
$message = 'Please click "OK" to confirm';
echo ('<script>confirm("'.$message.'")</script>');
```

Will become

```
<script>confirm("Please click "OK" to confirm")</script>
```

Which is of course invalid because of the mismatch of apostrophes.

You could do something like this.

```
$message = file_get_contents("my_gdpr_text.txt");
$message = json_encode($message);
echo ('<script>confirm('.$message.')</script>');
```

See also:

- [How do I pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)
- [How to escape string from PHP for javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085648/how-to-escape-string-from-php-for-javascript)

Also consider if you really need PHP:

- [How do I load the contents of a text file into a javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable)

Comment: Thanks for answer. The file contains no double-quotes. It is a numbered list of restrictions about not violating an individual's racial or ethnic origin etc.
However I don't know if it's confidential so dare not put it out here.

Comment: And no, json_encode makes no difference... :\

Comment: @PerryJ We don't need real file contents, lorem ipsum could be used, just include any non word characters that are in real file, ms quotes, non latin chars, etc.

Comment: @PerryJ you could also start debugging it by first creating a txt file that has only one word in it, to get minimal working solution. After that start adding parts from original file, to see where it breaks.

Comment: I have figured out there appears to be some limit of maximum 60 characters allowed.
It all works if I reduce the file to:
'Please be advised that care should be taken when entering a'
But:
'Please be advised that care should be taken when entering any' - does not work.

Comment: @PerryJ Probably best off using a modal in that case.

Comment: Likely you have to encode your text file with linux EOL, see what does \n and \r\n